# How to protect PC from any RF emanations?

Tags: security

I'm looking for answer of question: How to protect PC from any RF emanations?

There is main problem "Cooling" against RF proof enclosure.

I'm interest in building a crypto-station that proof against any TEMPEST attack.

For a while, emanations from monitor and keyboard are not so serious. And i try to solve problem of shielding ATX case against RF.

Comment: Build a Faraday cage.

Comment: Me need internet.

Comment: OK. Me need internet, too.

Comment: Fun. Is it joke?

Comment: Use a different computer for the Internet!

Comment: 2Brian Drummond, i do. Thanx. 2Moderators, What is unclear? RF emanations doesn't relate to electronics.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 6):

Put your laptop inside a large Faraday cage made of copper mesh, and use a fiberoptic connection to the internet. Although it seems that Tempest would be the least of your worries if you are connected to the internet...